# Kerberos Login using keytab without prompt for credentaials

Tags: hadoop, single-sign-on, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos, kerberos-delegation

I have done the following changes in the jaas.conf

```
kblogininfo
{
 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
 storekey=true
 useKeyTab=true
 useTicketCache=true
 doNotPrompt=true
 keyTab="/home/impadmin/kyvosworkspace/olapengine/connections/vikas.keytab"
 principal="vikas@KYVOSTEST.COM";
};
Client 
{
 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
 storekey=true
 useKeyTab=true
 useTicketCache=true
 doNotPrompt=true 
keyTab="/home/impadmin/kyvosworkspace/olapengine/connections/vikas.keytab"
 principal="vikas@KYVOSTEST.COM";
};
```

But still I am getting the prompt for credentials. Any help on this would be appreciable.

Comment: Add some debug flags on the Java command line (or set the properties in your code, as you prefer) to see if, and how, JAAS reads these two "contexts" >> `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext`

Comment: Thanks @Samson Scharfrichter